# Redirect content to another domain; specific folders - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to htaccess and hoping you can help please.

I have been given this in an htaccess file by a supplier:

```
Condition %{HTTP_HOST}    ^/World/environment/
RewriteRule http://world.environment.net/$1
```

No redirect happens when I run it thought.

What I'm hoping to do is to rewrite a page

```
http://myserver.com/World/environment/pages/pageX.html
```

on my server to:

```
http://world.environment.net/pages/pageX.html
```

I've been reading a lot of how htaccess works however I just can't seem to get my head around this bit.

Could someone please help this girl out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Condition` should be `RewriteCond`, and the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable *will never* match `^/World/environment/`. The Host request header contains only one thing, the hostname that the request is for. There is no path information in the Host field. Secondly, your rewrite rule needs a pattern, what's in the condition should be in the rule. You want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?World/environment/(.*)$ http://world.environment.net/$1 [L,R]
```

This is a **redirect**, which means the browser is told to load the new URL, thus changing what's in the browser's location bar. You also use the word "**rewrite**" which isn't the same thing. Rewrites happen entirely on the server's side, changing the URI without telling the browser that it's been changed. You can't do this kind of rewrite when the servers are different. The best you can do here is reverse proxy by changing the `R` flag in the rule to a `P`. This requires that you have mod_proxy loaded.

Comment: Thanks Jon; it looks like the supplier might have steered us incorrectly :)  Your explaination makes sense to me; thanks for the plain explaination!

Could you please let me know if there is a querystring at the end of the URL, if that is carried over too eg: 

http://myserver.com/World/environment/pages/pageX.html?id=australia